# Express proper way to handle routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

See my situation is that I had initialized the express.js library  to a variable and was asking is there a way to pass the express variable from app.js to users.js .My understanding was it cannot be done and I had to import it in users.js seperately if I wanted to use express libraries functions in user.js

Then I saw the below apporach

What I saw was 
App.js

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();
//Some code...
//Some code...
  var users = require('./routes/users.js');
  app.use('/',users);
```

Routes/User.js

```
   module.exports = (app,passport) = > {
   app.get('/route/',(req,res)=>{

  });

}
```

What I was doing until now was to require it in that js file as well .So what is the best way to handle such a situation

App.js

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();

//Some code...
//Some code...
  var users = require('./routes/users.js');
  app.use('/',users);
```

Routes/User.js

```
var express= require('express');
var router= express();

   router.get('/route/',(req,res)=>{
     //some action
  });

 module.exports = router;
```

And also how using ecma script the variable

**EDIT :-**

How does this code work without importing the express variable in users.js
app.js

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();

var users = require('./routes/users.js');
app.use('/',users);
```

route/users.js

```
module.exports = (app)=>{

    app.get('',(req,res)=>{
   //some code
   });
}
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear what your question is. Also, what file is the first 
`module.exports` you mentioned located in?

Comment: the module.exports is in routes/users.js and that is imported to app.js using app.use()

Comment: Actually, it is imported to `app.js` with `require`. Without that line, `app.use()` will just result in an error. Next, what variable are you asking about in the final line of your question?

Comment: I'd definitely use Express Router http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html to be able to organize code and to have relatively 'smaller' and more readable files to work with

Comment: @t3__rry Can you please check out the edit and tell me how without import the code works

Comment: @SachinDivakar I can't figure out why you don't want to be requiring Express in your `users` route
BTW here's the correct URL to Express Router: http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#router

Comment: See I was trying learn best practices figuring about stuff about the set up.I did many things without knowing how stuff properly by reading the documentation and example so .Trying to figure out reason behind the way we do stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express did actually introduced `Express.Router` for the second usecase, so yes its perfectly valid:

```
const express= require('express');
const router= express.Router();

router.get('/route/', (req,res) => {
 //some action
});

module.exports = router;
```

The first approach works too but i think it only complicates things. If you really need something (e.g. `passport`) in two different files you should extract it into a seperate module and import it at both locations. If you really want to pass values up the import chain, you actually need to call it when requiring:

```
//user.js
module.exports = app => {
 app.get("/user", "whatever");
}

//app.js
const app = express();
require("/user.js")(app); // <---
```

Comment: You don't answer the question about ECMAScript variables.

Comment: yes I have passport right now and was working with it and the confusion arised because I was using the normal approach of importing library in respective files but since I was trying to compartmentalize code and was trying brush up on best practices and i found this way .Can you please check out the edit and tell me how without import the code works

Comment: @sachin the second way actually wont work in the way you show it. See my edit :)

Comment: @sachin thats a function call?

Comment: @sachin no worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, using ECMAScript with variables is super simple. Just use `let` in place of `var`. The difference is in scoping. `var` automatically assigns the variable to the global scope, which means it can be accessed throughout the file. This can lead to problems in large, complex files if you accidentally use the same variable name twice. `let`, on the other hand, only assigns the variable to the local scope. So if you use `let` inside, say, a function, it will only exist inside that function. Therefore if you use the same variable name outside that function the file will run as expected.

Second, while the nature of the alternative approach you suggest is not entirely clear, you generally need to `require` a library in each file in which it is used. Even if through tinkering you somehow find another approach that works, this is generally accepted as a best practice.

Comment: I rephrased my question and I hope you understand what I was talking about.Basically it was about passing variable between one js file to another

Comment: With the additional context provided, I stand by the answer I provided.

Comment: Sorry I am in a bit confused state of mind and cant seem to put my thoughts clearly for you all to understand .But I have filtered it and made it as direct as I cant can you check out the edit and tell me how the code execution works there